# apache chemistry session with spring

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am currently developping java/jee app using spring as framework and alfresco as ged. I am using apache chemistry to connect to the alfresco repository.
This the code I am using to get a session.

Is there a way to change this code with spring bean because I`m going to use this session in diffrent classes and it would be better to be singleton.

```
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user credentials
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "admin");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "admin");

    // connection settings
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    System.out.println(BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    // set the alfresco object factory
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");

    // create session
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Session session = factory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0).createSession();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare it as a bean:

```
@Bean
public Session sessionBean() {
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // ...
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Session session = factory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0).createSession();
    return session;
}
```

So you can inject this session bean wherever you need.

Comment: normally i have to add this bean in the application context file is that right ?

Comment: From [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html): `@Bean is a method-level annotation and a direct analog of the XML <bean/> element.`